# Yielding a TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 4. This error was from the user_input variable associated with strong input

Tags: python-3.x

```
def randomLetters():
    numbers = [random.randint(0, 25), random.randint(0, 25)]
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    letters = [alphabet[numbers[0]], alphabet[numbers[1]]]
    return letters

letters = randomLetters()
print(letters)
print(letters[0])
user_input = input('Enter a word that begins with', "'" + letters[0] + "'", 'and ends with', "'" + letters[1] + "': ")
new_user_input = user_input.lower()

while (new_user_input[0] != letters[0]) and (new_user_input[len(new_user_input) - 1] != letters[1]):
    print('Invalid input. Try again.')
    new_user_input = input('Enter a word that begins with', "'" + letters[0] + "'", 'and ends with', "'" + letters[1] + "': ")
```

The user_input variable input is producing a TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 4

Answer (score 0):

`input()` only take one arg and you are providing it 4, the `,` separates arguments, perhaps you meant `+`:

```
new_user_input = input('Enter a word that begins with' + "'" + letters[0] + "'" +
                       'and ends with' + "'" + letters[1] + "': ")
```

`format()` helps constructing these strings simpler:

```
new_user_input = input("Enter a word that begins with '{letters[0]}' and ends with '{letters[1]}': ".format(letters=letters))
```